# How to add new classes to angular bootstrap UI directive elements?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a new class for the element created by the angular bootstrap UI directive. Neither options="" or ng-class="" managed to add a new class for the element:

```
<p class="stat" popover-placement="left" popover-title="'Help title" popover="This is the content of the popover" options="{popoverClass: 'popover my-class'}" ng-class="{'my-class': 1==1}"><span class="number">?</span></p>
```

This adds a new element when clicked from an angular bootstrap template.

Is there a way to customize directive elements with new classes without putting them into a container or changing the template?

Thank you!